# Using Spring Framework Web when Tomcat is already installed and running

Tags: spring, tomcat, web

I am studying Spring Framework (all features) preparing to start some microservices and web applications for the first time.  I am puzzled by the injection of Tomcat by Spring.  If I buy Java hosting with Tomcat already running or set up tomcat to be already configured and supposedly running on a server, is this going to cause a conflict because it is also included in Spring?  Or are we talking two different things where what is included in Spring is a connector to Tomcat instead of Tomcat itself?

Comment: Spring is NOT bundled with Tomcat, but Spring Boot does, anyway we can deploy spring boot web application in standalone tomcat as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about Spring Boot which comes with bundled tomcat (JAR packing). If you package as a JAR, tomcat will be bundled but if you want to use your own tomcat or Jetty or whatever you should look at bundling as WAR file which will exclude tomcat bundling.

few pointers for you

https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications

https://therealdanvega.com/blog/2017/06/28/deploying-war-application-server-spring-boot